# Laravel equivalent or alternative for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out how to do the equivalent of the following in Laravel that I would do in CodeIgniter all the time to build views:

```
$section = $this->load->view('pages/about', $data, TRUE);
```

This would allow me to echo `$section` in another view file and then when that view was called the normal way, it would render it. I am not sure how to do something like this in Laravel.

UPDATE

I figured it out. What I was needing was Laravel's HtmlString class to take a string and convert it to html markup to the view file.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views

Comment: You can do this one of three ways: [ViewComposers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers), by [sharing data with all views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views), or with [Service Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#service-injection) in your Blade template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the View Facade, so make sure to include it with an "Use" statement in your Controller, but basically is this:

```
$html = View::make('pages/about', $data)->render();
```

The `render()` method will just render the view in HTML, instead of returning it as a Response object like the `view()` helper function does.

Comment: I just read in the documentation that this returns a string. When I save this to a variable and echo it inside a view it literally prints the raw HTML. CI would basically "write" the view to the file. I was able to figure out how to do this with extending layouts using `@section` and `@yield`, however if I return more than one view in a foreach loop then ultimately only the last view gets rendered.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do so, try this:

```
return view('admin.profile', $data);
```

Read through this doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views